# How to take multiple multiline input variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, input, raw-input

Is it possible to take multiple newline inputs into multiple variables & declare them as `int` all at once?

To explain further what I am trying to accomplish, I know this is how we take space separated input using map:

```
>>> a, b = map(int, input().split())
3 5
>>> a
3
>>> b
5
```

Is there an equivalent for a newline? Something like:

`a, b = map(int, input().split("\n"))`

Rephrasing: I am trying to take multiple integer inputs, from multiple lines at once.

Comment: So you want something where 3 and 5 are on separate lines and the input keeps getting eaten? What should the resulting data structure look like? And when should you stop eating input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said it; I don't think you can do it with `input()`.

But you can do it like this:

```
import sys
numbers = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.read().split()]
```

Remeber that you can finish your entry by pressing `Ctrl+D`, then you have a list of numbers, you can print them like this (just to check if it works):

```
for num in numbers:
    print(num)
```

Edit:
for example, you can use an entry like this (one number in each line):

```
1
543
9583
0
3
```

And the result will be: `numbers = [1, 543, 9583, 0, 3]`

Or you can use an entry like this:

```
1
53          3
3 4 3 
      54
2
```

And the result will be: `numbers = [1, 53, 3, 4, 3, 54, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question,you want to read the input until `EOF` character is reached and extract the numbers from it:

```
[ int(x.strip()) for x in sys.stdin.read().split() ]
```

It stop once `ctrl+d` is sent or the `EOF` characted on the entry is reached.

For example, this entry:

```
1 43 43   
434
56 455  34
434 

[EOF]
```

Will be read as: `[1, 43, 43, 434, 56, 455, 34, 434]`

Answer (score 0):

You really cannot, `input` and `raw_input` stop reading and return when a new line is entered; there's no way to get around that from what I know. From [`input`s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

A viable solution might be calling `input` in a loop and joining on `'\n'` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

a, b = (int(input()) for _ in range(2))

Answer (score 0):

If you have mean read multiple variables from multiple inputs:

```
a, b, c = map(int, (input() for _ in range(3)))
```

Comment: Multi line inputs can be multiple lines. It could be 1 line, 2 lines, 3 lines, or 10 lines. Why is your program limiting the input to 3 lines only? Also, the question asks for space separator. Did you consider that